# Box with expanded border on one side

Tags: html, css, border

I have been sitting on this problem for a few days already, searching through a dozen StackOverflow answers, but to no avail.

[image: Picture]

I want to implement a dynamic box like the one in the picture.

All my current tries have not been successful, I got it working with all 4 sides expanding, or only working with a fixed box size(if the box size changed, all would break), but that's not what I'm trying to achieve here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
I tried modifying the answers of this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735698/extended-borders-with-css), but I couldn't make it work with just one line expanding, like in the image.

"dynamic" might have been the wrong word choice, I just meant for it to be responsive, without breaking the expanded border line.

Comment: can you add your current code and clarify how you want the 'dynamic' functionality to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this work for you?

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/4q9c27h5/)

```css
.box {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    background: white;
    border: 10px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

/* Adding the extended line */
.box:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    top: -40px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 10px;
    background: blue;
}

/* Dynamic height for test purposes */
.box:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```